# Add double quote between text seperated by comma

Tags: php, quote

I'm trying to figure out how to add double quote between text which separates by a comma.

e.g. I have a string

```
$string = "starbucks, KFC, McDonalds";
```

I would like to convert it to

```
$string = '"starbucks", "KFC", "McDonalds"';
```

by passing $string to a function. Thanks!

EDIT: For some people who don't get it...
I ran this code

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE id= 1');
$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo ' $result['testing']';
```

This returns the strings I mentioned above...

Comment: You have a string `$string = starbucks, KFC, McDonalds` how can that even be?

Comment: `$string = starbucks, KFC, McDonalds` gives a syntax error. Did you mean to have quotes around it?

Comment: I actually get that string from my database and that column returns that string. But I need to add quotes between those texts seperate by a comma.

Comment: How did it get in there in the first place? Plus, you'd need to add a semi-colon at the end of it to make it valid.

Comment: @rvighne yea, it's just an example... it suppose to be $string = "starbucks, KFC, McDonalds"

Comment: @nodeffect That's not an example, that's just wrong and confusing.

Comment: @ChrisHarrison: I think the OP requested that string from his/her database and just copy-paste'd it into here.

Comment: If you get it from the database, is it originally a string or a series of rows?

Comment: Please look back the question, I've added my code... it returns starbucks, KFC, McDonalds and I want to add quotes between them...

Comment: And why people would simply down vote just because you don't get it...

Comment: `$string = "starbucks", "KFC", "McDonalds"` - is that an array or a string? In fact it's neither in PHP, so you need to clarify this.

Comment: Ok. I for one would like to know if this => `$string = starbucks, KFC, McDonalds` is what's stored in your DB, or this => `starbucks, KFC, McDonalds` - As it stands, your question doesn't make any sense at all. Is it inside the same row, different rows? You're not being clear as to how that's being pulled out.

Comment: @rvighne Yes, regardless of whether it comes from a database or whatever else, you are quoting it as PHP and it's invalid PHP. If it ends up in PHP and is a string just put quotes around it.

Comment: @ChrisHarrison: I know, I wasn't saying it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work like a charm:

```
$parts = split(', ', 'starbucks, KFC, McDonalds');

echo('"' . join('", "', $parts) . '"');
```

**Note:** *As it has noticed in the comments (thanks, nodeffect), "**split**" function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Use "**explode**", instead.*

Comment: Thanks, this is shorter and it works... but I use explode and implode for split and join... cuz I receive a warning saying it's depreciated.

Comment: @nodeffect Nice! But only "split" function is obsolete. You can still use "join" as alias for "implode", it is ok.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, make your string a proper string as what you've supplied isn't. (pointed out by that cutey [**Fred -ii-**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028033/add-double-quote-between-text-seperated-by-comma/24028083?noredirect=1#comment37039468_24028033)).

```
$string = 'starbucks, KFC, McDonalds';
$parts = explode(', ', $string);
```

As you can see the explode sets an array `$parts` with each name option. And the below foreach loops and adds your `"` around the names.

```
$d = array();
foreach ($parts as $name) {
    $d[] = '"' . $name . '"';
}
```

`$d` Returns:

```
"starbucks", "KFC", "McDonalds"
```

*probably not the quickest way of doing it, but does do as you requested.*

[As **`this.lau_`** pointed out, its most definitely a duplicate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028033/add-double-quote-between-text-seperated-by-comma/24028083?noredirect=1#comment37039636_24028083)

And if you want a simple option, go with [**`felipsmartins answer`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24028106/2518525) :-)

Comment: *"(pointed out by that cutey Fred -ii-)"* ROLMHO! Aw gee, thanks! That deserves a +1 just cuz ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- What can I say, you do know how to charm the OP's ;-)

Comment: In my own little way(s), sure. At times I'm not so flattering lol!

Comment: I did a lil mistakes and get a downvote straight without me correcting it first

Comment: @Fred-ii- Haha you must be my brother from another mother!

Comment: If the answer is `explode(',', $string)`, it's probably a duplicate of 1000 other questions :)

Comment: You should have a look at functional programming style, array_map function will do the work in more elegant way than foreach

Comment: @denied stated in answer already...

Comment: @Darren So far, OP hasn't accepted nor commented on any of the answers given. [`See what I asked the OP`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028033/add-double-quote-between-text-seperated-by-comma#comment37039783_24028033) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic function, without any checks (i.e. $arr should be an array in array_map and implode functions, $str should be a string, not an array in explode function):

```
function get_quoted_string($str) {
  // Here you will get an array of words delimited by comma with space
  $arr = explode (', ', $str);   
  // Wrapping each array element with quotes
  $arr = array_map(function($x){ return '"'.$x.'"'; }, $arr); 
  // Returning string delimited by comma with space
  return implode(', ', $arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Came in my mind a really nasty way to do it. `explode()` on comma, `foreach` value, `value = '"' . $value . '"';`, then run `implode()`, if you need it as a single value.

Answer (score 0):

And you're sure that's not an array?  Because that's weird.

But here's a way to do it, I suppose...

```
$string = "starbucks, KFC, McDonalds";

// Use str_replace to replace each comma with a comma surrounded by double-quotes.
// And then shove a double-quote on the beginning and end
// Remember to escape your double quotes...

$newstring = "\"".str_replace(", ", "\",\"", $string)."\"";
```